# What is the intended/better way to offload route handling to a different class in Spark Java?

Tags: spark-java

I'm trying to separate different sub-path handling into different classes using following route definition:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    port(Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT")));
    staticFileLocation("/public");

    get("/test", (req, res) -> "OK");
    path("/api", () -> {
        path("/x", () -> {
            post("/action1",      (request, response) -> XAPIHandler.action1(request, response));
        });
        path("/y", () -> {
            post("/action1",       (request, response) -> YAPIHandler.action1(request, response));
            post("/action2",       (request, response) -> YAPIHandler.action2(request, response));
            post("/action3",       (request, response) -> YAPIHandler.action3(request, response));
            get("/action4",        (request, response) -> YAPIHandler.action4(request, response));
        });
    });
}
```

I then have the following API handler class structure:

```
public class YAPIHandler {

    public static Object action1(Request request, Response response) {
        try {
            //Some logic goes here
            response.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            response.status(200);
            response.body(myJsonObject.serialize()); //a bit of pseudocode here, in reality using Gson library
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.status(500);
            response.body("Some error message");
        }
        return response.body();
    }
    ...
}
```

This particular approach seems ok to me and was working well, until in one particular scenario (`actionZ`) it started returning 404 regardless of what status has been set via `response.status(...)`.  After some testing I realised it was because `actionZ` was not returning anything to user apart from 200 status in case of success and so response body was never explicitly set. Calling `response.body("")` has fixed the 404 issue, but made me realise there is something I don't understand about how Spark Java framework works and made me doubt if separate API handler classes was the right approach to begin with.

**2 questions:**

1. Is there a way to return 200 ok response with empty body using above code structure without explicitly calling `response.body("")`?
2. Is there an alternative way to split handler logic into separate classes that is more in-line with Spark "ways of doing things"?

**P.S.** I saw that Spark documentation on routes seems to suggest some sort of handler decomposition in following example:

```
path("/api", () -> {
    before((q, a) -> log.info("Received api call"));
    path("/email", () -> {
        post("/add",       EmailApi.addEmail);
        put("/change",     EmailApi.changeEmail);
        delete("/remove",  EmailApi.deleteEmail);
    });
    path("/username", () -> {
        post("/add",       UserApi.addUsername);
        put("/change",     UserApi.changeUsername);
        delete("/remove",  UserApi.deleteUsername);
    });
});
```

but I was unable to replicate it. So if someone could provide a sample structure for EmailApi class from above example with method signatures and return values, that would probably be the answer to Q2 that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting status to 200 without using `body()` afterwards:

```
Spark.get("/", (req, res) -> {
    res.status(200);
    return "";
});
```

Delegating work to certain handlers can be done via java8 method references.
Imagine you have a method like this in a `class LoginHandler`:

```
public static String login(Request req, Response res) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Then in your main class you could call:

```
Spark.get("/login", LoginHandler::login);
```

Regarding serialization into json or other formats I suggest you take a look at the

*Response Transformer*

section of the docs: http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#response-transformer

Comment: Thanks! "java8 method references" was the bit I was missing!